# How to display image angular from .net core API and database

Tags: c#, .net, angular, database

I would like to display a picture whose path it stores in the database

this is how it transfers the image file to the database.

```
        public string UploadImage(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null) throw new Exception("Pusty plik");
            if (file.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Pusty plik");
            }
            if (!ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES.Any(s => s == Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower())) throw new Exception("Zły typ pliku");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host.WebRootPath))
            {
                host.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
            }
            var uploadFilesPath = Path.Combine(host.WebRootPath, "images");
            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFilesPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFilesPath);
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesPath, fileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"/wwwroot/images/", fileName);

            return path;
        }
```

here stores files:
https://zapodaj.net/a8829a7a3a90b.png.html

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code I do not see path returning from database.

Also from security point of view it would be bad practice to return `/wwwroot/images/` in response. You can create a folder on shared location and return shared location path.

Seems you question and same code isn't aligning.

Comment: this is the return path: /wwwroot/images/4f25c59f-4e5d-4a52-8e4a-5e621a59b5dc.png

Comment: I'd avoid returning /wwwroot/images/ in response.